# When comparing series, i'm having trouble understanding how my book determines which is greater than the other

Tags: sequences-and-series

For example, by book says the series $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n} -1}$$ is greater than
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Yet when I enter both An and Bn in my calculator, It seems to me that the value of Bn is always greater.

Comment: I'm sorry I should clarify that An is the first series, while Bn is the latter.

Comment: In general, if $a,b >0$ we have ${1 \over a+b} < {1 \over a}$.

Comment: The book is right. When the denominator of a fraction decreases its value increases (positive numerator and denominator). I don't know what you asked your calculator to do.

Comment: Are you computing $\sqrt{n}-1$ or $\sqrt{n-1}$ in your calculator? One possible explanation for the mistake can be this.

Comment: Wow, very fast answers. Thanks guys.

The issue was that I was entering it into my calculator wrong, it was computing the division then subtracting 1 rather than subtracting 1 first.

Comment: Apologies if anything i did is frowned upon, this is my first post.

Comment: @gibford The series diverge and therefore there is no ordering applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic point lies in the fact that, for any positive $n>1$
$$\sqrt{n}-1 \leq \sqrt{n}$$
$$\implies \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}-1} \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$
$$\implies \boxed{\sum_{n=2}^M \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}-1} \geq \sum_{n=2}^M \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}} \,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{for any finite positive integer M}$$

However, the inequality will have no meaning if $M \to \infty$. Since, then, both the summations become divergent.

Comment: Note that both series are divergent. So the last inequality is meaningless.

Comment: @mfl Yes, the inequality is meaningless. But that is what is being talked about in this question unfortunately.

Comment: @Dr.MV Thanks for your comment. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For any $n\in\mathbb{N},n\ge 2$ it is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt n-1}\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt n}.$$ So, $$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{\sqrt n-1}\ge \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{\sqrt n}$$ for any $N\in\mathbb{N},N\ge 2.$

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
\sqrt{n}-1<\sqrt{n},\qquad n=1,2,3,\cdots,
$$ giving
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{n}-1}>\frac1{\sqrt{n}},\qquad n=2,3,\cdots,
$$ and by summing
$$
\sum_{n=2}^N \frac1{\sqrt{n}-1}>\sum_{n=2}^N \frac1{\sqrt{n}}
$$ but, as $N \to \infty$, both series are **divergent**:
$$
\lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{n=2}^N \frac1{\sqrt{n}-1}=\lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{n=2}^N \frac1{\sqrt{n}}=\infty.
$$